# How do I become better at counter play when I'm down in material?

Tags: best-practice, counterplay

How do I practice counter play when I'm down material?

Answer (score 1):

Counter play, especially when down material, is often about creating dynamic chances. So you should probably work in that area:

- Study the games of some attacking geniuses like [Tal](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1139582), [Shirov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1085871), [Morphy](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1238130), [Anderssen](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1019162).
- Work through some [good](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486284492) [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857444000) on [attacking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9197600407) [chess](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983250).
- Play some gambits in training games.
- Train tactics, but thats a given anyway.